# Как задать значения аргумента “start” в функции stats4::mle в R?

Tags: r, статистика

Жаль, что я не могу скинуть полностью воспроизводимый код проблемы, потому что я использую конкретный большой вектор. Но в принципе проблема и так довольно ясная. Я пытаюсь найти параметры бета распределения с помощью функции **mle**:

```
params <- mle(nll, start = list(alpha = 0.1, beta = 10), method = "L-BFGS-B")
```

Где nll - функция для отрицательного логарифмического правдоподобия. В документации для функции mle говорится, что start - это исходные значения, с которого она начинает приближения.

После перебора нескольких вариантов мне подошли мои 0.1 и 10. Но сейчас я пытаюсь приблизить разные части того же вектора по некоему фактору и эти же параметры уже не подходят. На некоторых частях я получаю такую ошибку:

```
Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn' 
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lbeta(shape1[okk] + x[okk], shape2[okk] + size[okk] - x[okk]) :
NaNs produced
2: In lbeta(shape1[okk], shape2[okk]) : NaNs produced
```

В интернете я наткнулся на хорошую идею начать приближение со значений, полученных [методом моментов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Method_of_moments). Так что я заменил свои 0.1 и 10 на эти формулы, но получаю ту же самую ошибку.

Знаете ли Вы какой-то способ задать точно подходящие начальные значения для приближения бета распределения функцией **mle**?

Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, я не нашел как найти стопроцентно подходящие начальные значения, но нашёл как избежать ошибок:

1. Просто поменять метод на `"BFGS"`. Он выдаст предупреждения, но без ошибок.

или

2. Отдельно указать аргументы `lower` и `upper`.